# How to add an notifcation function in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, alarm

I am writing a shell and set an alarm in the code:
if user didn't input anything in 5 seconds,then the shell will ask the user "You didn't input in 5 seconds ,do you want to shutdown [Y/N]?"

My code is as fllows:

```
while(1){
int pid = fork();
if(lt_start == NULL){
    lt_start = time(NULL);// 
}
if (pid==0)// child proecess
{
    int cur= getpid();
    lt_input=  time(NULL);
    if(lt_input-lt_start>5){
        int len_command = 0;
        char character;
        printf("You don't input 5 seconds, do you want to teminate programm [Y/N]? ");


        while((character=getchar())!='\n')
        {

            commandStr[len_command]=character;
            len_command++;
        }
    commandStr[len_command]='\0';
          // do something depend on user input Y OR N

    }

}else

{

char character;
    int len_command = 0;
//      alramhandler(SIGINT, lt_start);

    while((character=getchar())!='\n')
    {

        commandStr[len_command]=character;
        len_command++;
    }

    commandStr[len_command]='\0';
        // implement user input


   }
```

Every time you input a character,it will be implement in parent process. I don't know how to modify it?

How should I change my code : let it show alarm after 5 seconds even I didn't input any shell?

Comment: Use `alarm(5);`. Five seconds later, you'll get a SIGALRM.

Comment: My code is as follows,however, the alarm doesn't work after it implement "doMain()" in the "handler2()", I don't know why? My code as follows: